# What does one do when Wolframalpha fails to solve an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-calculus

I'm looking for an analytic solution to this integral:

$$
\int\sqrt{\left(\frac{2 d}{(1 + 4 x ^ 2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} + 1\right) \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 + 4 x ^ 2}}}dx, d > -0.5
$$

Wolframalpha fails to find a solution to this, and using quadratures for evaluation is too slow for my use case since I need this for a real-time application.

What does one do in such cases? My intuition is to try to find a function that approximates the integral decently enough on a graphic calculator, but it's quite challenging to start from scratch.

The challenging part of this integral is the $+ 1$ in the first term. Without it, the solution is trivial.

Update:

The closest approximation I found is this:

$$
\frac{6 x \sqrt{\frac{2 d}{\sqrt{1 + 4 x ^ 2}} + 1}}{\sqrt[4]{9 ^ 2 x ^ 2 + 8 ^ 2} + 2}
$$

How could I improve the accuracy of this?

Comment: Well, for one, WolframAlpha is far from infallible, so it's genuinely possible this might be able to be integrated anyways. Sometimes we gotta put in the hard work. ... Not that I have a clue as to whether this is actually integrable in the first place.

Comment: _When Wolframalpha fails to solve an integral it is very possible that is practical impossible to find a closed form of the givens integral.There are other methods to find a function that will approximate it.Some of this methods are:_                                             
1.Method of Simpson and 2.Method of Newton-Cotes .Links:



   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule (wiki theory-Simpson method)
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EqRRuh-5Lk (video about Simpson method)
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cotes_formulas (wiki-Newton-Coted)

Comment: @ConstantinosPisimisis The numerical methods are too slow for what I need and also quite unpredictable. For some intervals, only a few samples are needed. For others, you might need hundreds or thousands.

Comment: I don't know, cry?

Comment: @dragostis Yes they may be slow but if the integral can not be calculated in a closed form i am afraid that numeric methods are the only availabe option.I don't know if you can use MatLab or anythying similar to speed up the process in numeric methods.

Comment: Maybe use the binomial series for $\sqrt{y+1}$ if the integral of the sum still converges?

Comment: What numerical method did you use to estimate the value of the integral? Perhaps you could use a better numerical method or implement the method more efficiently. For example, if your implementation was in Python and used for loops, it could easily be 100x slower than necessary.

Comment: The simplest case appears to be $d=\frac12$, in which case the integral does have a closed form expression in terms of elliptic integrals. However, for all other positive values of $d$ it reduces to a nontrivial hyperelliptic integral of degree $5$. So a general analytic solution to your integral doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Since the analytic solution is highly unlikely, could you provide a little more context about the origin of the integrand, the environment you want to evaluate the integral in (there is a wide gap of efficiency between some high-level language and low-level things like on-GPU or embedded hardware) and the precision required for your use-case? Do you need to compute the value for one $d$ at a time or many of them at once? Are they random or tightly packed?

Comment: @dragostis: What is the region of integration? What values of $d$ are we interested in?

Answer (score 7):

First of all:

$$\sqrt{\frac{2d}{(4x^2+1)^\frac32}+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{\frac12}n\left(\frac{2d}{(4x^2+1)^\frac32}\right)^n= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{\frac12}n(2d)^n(4x^2+1)^{-\frac{3n}2}$$

Therefore:

$$\int\sqrt{\left(\frac{2 d}{(1 + 4 x ^ 2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} + 1\right)} \frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt[4]{1 + 4 x ^ 2}} dx= \sqrt2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{\frac12}n(2d)^n\int\frac1{\sqrt[4]{4 x ^ 2+1}}(4x^2+1)^{-\frac{3n}2}dx$$

we [integrate](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ddx+%282%5E%28-3%2F2+%2B+n%29+d%5En+x+beta%28-4+x%5E2%2C+1%2F2%2C+3%2F4+-+%283+n%29%2F2%29%29%2Fsqrt%28-x%5E2%29) with the [incomplete beta function $\text B_z(a,b)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=beta%28z%2Ca%2Cb%29):

$$\int\sqrt{\frac2{\sqrt{4x^2+1}}\left(\frac{2 d}{(1 + 4 x ^ 2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} + 1\right)}dx=-\frac{i\text{sgn}(x)}{2^\frac32}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{\frac12}n (2d)^n \text B_{-4x^2}\left(\frac12,\frac34-\frac{3n}2\right)$$

[**which**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5Bsqrt%28%282*1.3%2F%284x%5E2%2B1%29%5E%283%2F2%29%2B1%292%2F%28sqrt%284x%5E2%2B1%29%29%29%2C%7Bx%2C1.5%2C2%7D%5D) [**works**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-i%2F2%5E%283%2F2%29+Sum%5Bbinom%281%2F2%2Cn%29+%282d%29%5En+beta%28-4a%5E2%2C-4b%5E2%2C1%2F2%2C3%2F4-3n%2F2%29%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C20%7D%5D%2Ca%3D1.5%2Cb%3D2%2Cd%3D1.3) when comparing both test links’ results, where the $5$th term in the example is on the order of $10^{-8}$ with potentially faster decaying terms as $n\to\infty$. It also works for the binomial series radius of convergence $2|d|<(4x^2+1)^\frac32\iff d\ge\frac12,x>\pm\frac12\sqrt{(2d)^\frac23-1}$:

[image]

Now you have an analytic solution as requested

Comment: Can you really call an infinite series a solution to an integral without any bounds on how quickly the terms decay? The OP wants to actually compute some numbers.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan There will be a numerical example

Comment: Like @QiaochuYuan said, this solution produces good results, but it's still quite expensive to compute, especially since the incomplete beta function seems heavy to start with.

Comment: @dragostis Thanks for the review. Maybe another answer will have better results

Comment: For those curious, the beta function simplifies to elliptic integrals for $\text B_w\left(\frac12,\frac n4\right),n\in\Bbb N$, so it is not just a beta function

Comment: Since the edit, the formula also works for $|d|<\frac12$ for those curious

Answer (score 2):

This is what we have done in a context where we had to compute the solution of an equation system in $\mathbb{R}^4$, with time constraints like you have.

- Numerically (and offline), compute the integral for $N$ values of $d$, and the integration bounds if they vary.
- Find an approximation of the function which minimizes the maximum error on this set of $N$ values. You can use polynomials, linear combinations of positive and negative powers of variables, rational functions,... whatever seems more fitting and will not be too long to compute in your real-time application. You may probably find some python package to help finding the set of parameters that minimize the maximum error. There is a theory of [Padé approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) that may be relevant too, although I have not used it.
- Check the validity of the approximation on another set of points.

Comment: Padé approximants seem to be a good start, but they have singularities for some values of d. I guess the question is what kind of approximation function would work best for both d and the integral limits a and b.

Comment: @dragostis Yes, that's it. What worked well in our case was linear combinations of positive and negative powers of the variables. Rational fractions would be good candidates  too, because it is popular wisdom that they have a better interpolation behaviour than polynomials (although I cannot give a reference of a study on that).

Comment: @dragostis You can also look at Remez algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm) for finding a polynomial that minimizes the maximum absolute error. There is I believe a variant that allows multiple variables.